# How to read argv[1][1 - untill the end of the string] in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to read `argv[1]` starting from the *second character* until the end of the string in `argv[1]` (ignoring the first character, which is a flag). How can I do this?

I tried some library functions and other ways such as storing it in a variable such as

```
char *variable = strncpy(argv[1][1], strlen(argv[1]))
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked the signature of `strncpy`? And also can you please try to rephrase the question to something more clear?

Comment: What do you mean by "read" it?  If `argv[1]` is a string, then `argv[1] + 1` is the string you seem to want.  You don't need to read it--you already have it.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. This is what I am trying to do: given an input to my executable in the form of "+name" (which is argv[1]), I want to read the input starting from character "n" to the end of the string, skipping "+"

Comment: @coder.: What do you mean by read? You want to copy it to some char array so that you process it? And each of your argument to `main` would be liek this? `./a.out +name1 +name2 +name3`??

Comment: `char *p = argv[1];` would give you a pointer to the beginning of the string `"+name"`.  So then if you do `p += 1;`; you would advance the pointer past the `+` character, and get the argument.

Comment: Well thank you for taking the [tour].  Please read [Ask] and [MCVE].  "but it didn't work" is not a good problem statement.  Where is your code?  What were the results?  What exactly did you expect?  BTW: `char *p = &(argv[1][1]);` would work if you're just trying to skip the leading '-' or '/' characters in your program arguments.  It's equivalent to `char *p = argv[1] + 1;`.

Comment: `#include <string.h> .. size_t len = strlen (argv[1]); char variable[len]; strcpy (variable, argv[1] + 1); printf ("variable : %s\n", variable);` (note: this requires C99 (or newer) or VLA extensions to C89). Otherwise instead of `char varable[len];` use `char *variable = malloc (len); if (!varable) return 1;`

Answer (score 1):

You are running up against two fundamental misconceptions regarding variables and pointers in C.

Let's start with:

```
 char *variable = strncpy(argv[1][1], strlen(argv[1]))
```

The biggest problem (aside from the improper use of `strncpy`) is you attempt to assign the return of `strncpy` to `char *variable` where `char *variable` is a *pointer-to-char* that is uninitialized and points to no valid storage. Your attempt to assign the return fails because the proper prototype for `strncpy` is:

```
char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
```

(**note:** the `dest` parameter. The destination must have adequate storage to accept `n` characters`. **further note:** if there is no`null byte` among the first n bytes of src, the array of bytes placed in dest will not be a *null-terminated* string.)

Now either by cleverness or happy-circumstance using the `strlen` of the complete `argv[1]` to allocate storage for `dest` and copying from `argv[1] + 1` does provide space for the `null byte`.

Your next misconception is using `argv[1][1]` in `strncpy`. `argv[1][1]` has type `char`, not `char*`. (though your could use `&argv[1][1]` to use the *address of* `argv[1][1]` -- but not as you have it above.

`argv[1]` is a pointer of type `char *`. Being a pointer-to-char, if you want to skip one char, you want to read from the address `pointer + 1` (or `argv[1] + 1` in this case). Now it may make things easier to understand if you declare a separate pointer, e.g. `char *p = argv[1];` and then use `p + 1`, but it is the same thing.

Putting that together, it looks like you intended:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) 
        return 1;

    size_t len = strlen (argv[1]);
    char variable[len];

    strcpy (variable, argv[1] + 1); 
    printf ("variable : %s\n", variable);

    return 0;
}
```

Where with your example argument of `+name`, you would get:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/argv1plus1 +name
variable : name
```

For sake of completeness, if your compiler does not support use of a *Variable Length Array* (VLA) as used in `char variable[len];` above, then your options are to declare `variable` as a fixed size array and validate that `strlen(argv[1])` has no more characters than your fixed size, or, you simply allocate storage for `variable` dynamically by calling `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`). A short example using `malloc` would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) 
        return 1;

    size_t len = strlen (argv[1]);
    char *variable = malloc (len);  /* allocate a block of memory len chars long */

    if (variable == NULL) {         /* always validate malloc succeeded */
        perror ("malloc failure");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy (variable, argv[1] + 1); 
    printf ("variable : %s\n", variable);

    free (variable);   /* don't forget to free the memory you allocate */

    return 0;
}
```

(same example & output)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand it now.